# How to manipulate pixels in a Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am developing an Instagram like application for learning image processing and android. But I am stuck, I have a problem implementing Grayscale Filter in my application. I am trying a simple approach for now to convert individual pixels in a Bitmap to Grayscale.

Here's the whole class I am writing to apply various filters to an Image:

```
package com.dosa2.photoeditor.ImageEffects;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class ImageEffects {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    int width, height;

    public ImageEffects(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    public Bitmap toGrayscale() {

        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        p.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);

        return resultBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap toGrayscale2() {
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        for(int i=0;i<height;i++) {
            for (int j=0;i<width;j++) {
                int c = bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
                resultBitmap.setPixel(i, j, (Color.red(c)+Color.blue(c)+Color.green(c)/3));
            }
        }

        return resultBitmap;
    }
}
```

I have tried 2 methods to convert the Bitmap into Grayscale. The former seems to be working(but I am not able to understand it) and the latter is not. 
Can anyone help me out? And do mention if there's an easier way to manipulate Images in Android.

Comment: The former (using a ColorMatrix) is the most efficient one. Because it works on the entire bitmap at once, in a single step, instead of having to cycle into 2 loops. You may not understand ColorMAtrices, in the beginning, but there's a lot of documentation (not only in Java and not only for Android - I also use them in VB,NET and C#, for instance)

Comment: Where can i find the documentation or a good learning resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error (or at least one of them...) is in one of your for loops:

```
for (int j=0;i<width;j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
```

to prevent an indefinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, it worked!
What kind of a foolish I am :(
sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your method "toGrayscale" is using the ColorMatrix class, which I think internally uses the RenderScript API to do the rendering (or at least GPU shaders). RenderScript is the Android's computing API (which is similar to OpenCL, in fact, is a layer that works on OpenCL), so you are not using only the CPU to do the color filtering, you are using even the GPU or other DSPs your device may have. The second method "toGrayscale2" is slower because you are using only the CPU to convert your Bitmap to grayscale (pixel by pixel) and you shouldn't use it. Check [this presentation](https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/12) (it's very intersting) in order to understand a bit more how your first method works, the link points to the page 12 which is about color filtering, but you should view it entirely in order to understand better.

Comment: Thank you @josemgu91 but why the Canvas and Paint Classes?

Comment: @user5482992 As noted in the Canvas class docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html): "To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing).". I think that wilk help you to understand those classes better :).

Comment: Ohh.. I see. Now I can understand a little bit more. Thank you @josemgu91 :)